# Have to restart HTTPD sometimes to get back to normal

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

I recently have a problem with my dedicated server.

The problem is that, after a while (not exact time or period) I face an error in my website `website took too long to respond.` when I want to access it through chrome. And I have to `restart httpd restart` to get back to normal.

I've recently changed `MaxClients` , but the problem still exist.

Here is apache error_log file:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 18578:tid 47111993476864] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client x.183.x.146:51244] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19209:tid 47111943046912] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client x.193.x.239:33740] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17956:tid 47111972464384] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client x.183.x.37:54502] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 17865:tid 47111987173120] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client x.186.x.121:55530] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

Any Idea?